# Update data using n-tier does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got 3-tier where carry out my code in business layer I run code for update

```
public override bool LoadProperties2List(string TypeOfOperation)
{
  SortedList Sl = new SortedList();

  Sl.Add("@CommandType", TypeOfOperation);
  Sl.Add("@UserName",UserName);
  Sl.Add("@SecondarySchool",SecondarySchool);
  Sl.Add("@University",University);
  Sl.Add("@Qualification",Qualification);
  Sl.Add("@JobTitle",JobTitle);
  Sl.Add("@Company",Company);
  Sl.Add("@PhotoUrl", PhotoUrl);

  ProcedureName = "MangeUserInfo";
  if (db.RunProcedure(ProcedureName, Sl) == 1)
  return true;
  else
  return false;
}

public bool updateUser(string User, string SecondaryS, string Unvi, string Qua, string jobtitle, string company)
{
  this.UserName = User;
  this.SecondarySchool = SecondaryS;
  this.University = Unvi;
  this.Qualification = Qua;
  this.JobTitle = jobtitle;
  this.Company = company;

  if (Update())
  return true;
  else
  return false;
 }
```

and in data access layer

```
public void ConnectDB(CommandType CT,string ProNameSQl)
{
  cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Conversation;Integrated Security=True");
  cmd = new SqlCommand();

  cmd.Connection = cn;
  cmd.CommandType = CT;
  cmd.CommandText = ProNameSQl;
  cn.Open();
}

public int RunProcedure(string ProcedureName, SortedList Paraval)
{
  ConnectDB(CommandType.StoredProcedure, ProcedureName);

  for (int x = 0; x < Paraval.Count; x++)
  {
  try
  {

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Paraval.GetKey(x).ToString(), Paraval.GetByIndex(x));
  }
  catch
  {
  ;
  }
  }
  return ExceNoneQuery();
}
```

and then in another layer I use this method to call procedure process kind and run

```
public bool Update()
{
  return LoadProperties2List("u");
  }
```

at last layer presentation layer

I do that

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //upadate info
  bool Result = false;
  UsersInfo Upd = new UsersInfo();

  try
  {
  Result = Upd.updateUser(username, TxtSecondarySchool.Text, TxtUniversity.Text, TxtQualification.Text, TxtJobTitle.Text, TxtCompany.Text);
  if (Result==true)

  lblMessage.Text = "Record Updated Successfully.";

  else

  lblMessage.Text = "Record couldn't updated";

  }
  catch (Exception ee)
  {
  lblMessage.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
  }  finally
  {
  Upd = null;
  }
}
```

When I run the code only the result is

```
lblMessage.Text = "Record couldn't updated";
```

What is the error which makes it not to work correctly?

I also find something strange that the textboxes doesn't take the new values it pass the same value despite change why? I need help

Comment: You have an empty catch block in your try, so if you do encounter an error, it's getting swallowed.  Wrap the call to the database (the ExecuteNonQuery) in the try-catch as well - and put something in the catch block so you know what the error is.  If that doesn't help, step through the code in the debugger and see what is happening.

Comment: when i run debugger i find that all textboxes pass the loaded values not the new one ??? which edite  i use calender ajaxtoolkite and recaptch in my page

Comment: thankx for your advice i really do that to follow and know what happened i find that all textboxes pass the old values which load in page load all them doesnt pass the new values and so update happened with the data and so nothing happened the question which i search for why textboxes dont pass the new values ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that the textbox loads in a routine in the Page's Startup event, with the routine placed outside the If IsNotPostback loop. So, the default value just reloads every time the page is refreshed, and thus appears to be 'unchangeable'.